# Showing that an autoregressive time series depends only on the most recent and future values

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that I have an autoregressive time series model $x_1, x_2, ...$ where the mean is 0, autocorrelation 0.8, residual standard deviation of 1, and errors that are normal which are for all t:

$$
x_t |x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, ... \sim N(0.8 x_{t-1}, 1)
$$

I would like to show that the distribution of $x_t$, given all other time points $t$, should depend only on $x_{t-1}$ and $x_{t+1}$.

I have tried to condition backwards, but am unable to obtain the $x_{t+1}$. Does anyone have any hints for what approach I can take? Thanks!

Comment: Um... why should the distribution of $x_t$ depend on $x_{t+1}$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $x_t$ given all other time points $t$, depends on $x_{t-1}$ and $x_{t+1}$.

Comment: If $x_t\sim N(0.8x_{t-1},1)$, then I don't really see how $x_t$ depends on $x_{t+1}$. (That would be an, um, *non-standard* type of AR process.)

Comment: Just a note that this is a piece of a question from Gelman, [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/), 3rd ed., exercise 3.15 (p.82).